# Is there a way to detect when the actual DOM render completes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a Vue component that uses a charting library to draw charts on `canvas` elements. I want the charts to take up a width proportional to that of the window which means that the chart library doesn't know how big it needs to make its `canvas` element until after the virtual DOM has been rendered into the browser.

Is there some way I can trigger the rendering of the charts once the DOM has been rendered? Vue contains the `mounted` lifecycle hook but that is triggered too early and even using `$nextTick` after `mounted` is too early in the render pipeline.

Failing that, is there another (hack) way I can detect that the DOM has been generated so I can use that to trigger the chart render?

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitioning-state.html

Comment: Sadly not, there are no state transitions or data changes going on here. All the data is in place when the component is mounted.

Comment: `mounted()` should be the right point, or `$nextTick` inside `mounted()` if you need to wait for child components to finish rendering too... Is there something asynchronous you need to wait for as well?

Answer (score 0):

I hate to suggest this but as a work around you can add a `<script>...</script>` snippet which triggers an event (soon before the EOF the Vue component) which you can handle to call your graph render function. 
It should approximately look like this:

```
<vue-component> 
    <!-- component contents -->
    <!-- ... -->
    <script> // trigger-code </script> 
</vue-component>
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ref (see [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs)) to apply changes to the DOM.

Use it in the `mounted` hook in the same component that holds the `<canvas>` element.